# How to Resize Image in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How to resize image using [image_editor](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor) or any other library. I am used [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) library, but it gives error:

> D/OpenGLRenderer: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Answer (score 0):

Just a small tip: I would suggest including the code snippet to show exactly how you try to re-size, so others can explain why the error happens in the first place and help you do it the way you already started doing

There are multiple ways to do it in Flutter and it is not super clear which exactly you might need (static sizes, dynamic fitting, resizing meaning compression or etc). I assume we talk about image resizing to the static size for its further rendering.

One of them is simply using a `ConstrainedBox` as a parent widget on the `Image`.
For example ⬇️, just use the path to your own asset instead of `assets/vancouver.jpg` and then tweak `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` if the sizes are static.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0, maxWidth: 200.0),
          child: Image.asset("assets/vancouver.jpg"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: With this code can't save resized image on the device.

Comment: Ah, it also needs to be saved on the device. Sorry, it seems this wasn't mentioned in the original question.

@Jorpy can I ask you please to update the original question with more specific details?
1. What exactly do you need to do? (e.g. display image -> be able to resize it using buttons -> have a "download" button that saves resized image on the device)
2. What your code looks like right now and where the error is happening exactly?

Without this information I can only guess what is needed and as we see my first guess didn't work 

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress this package if you want to save file the small size image file.

The below method of `FlutterImageCompress` package gives an another file according to your needs, you've to simply decrease the quality of your image file.

```
Future<File> testCompressAndGetFile(File file, String targetPath) async {
var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
    file.absolute.path, targetPath,
    quality: 88,
    rotate: 180,
  );

print(file.lengthSync());
print(result.lengthSync());

return result;
  }
```

You can checkout other methods as well of this package that can help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: This library can't increase image dimensions; it only decreases.

Comment: You can use this package to save the image and if @IDobrodushniy's answer does your job you can use his approach with https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot